# show hide button in unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 15 buttons on my screen. 
In the onClick event I am fetching the button and hiding that button using

```
EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.SetActive(false);
```

At the end I have to show buttons again, so I am using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    tag1 = "Button" + (i + 1);
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag1).SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("done");
}
```

Loop is giving error because it is not able to find objects which has been hidden or setActive(false)
from other references ([unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-turn-on-off-button-visibility.290317/#post-1916554)) I see the same solution but I don't know why it is not working in my case.

Comment: Would be easier to get a reference to this button in script and just call `mebutton.SetActive(true)`

Comment: button does not contain setActive property @m.rogalski

Comment: @JamesHughes i tried reactivating all i knew Button11 was inactivated before and it printed "done" 10 times only issue isnot able "find object which has been hidden"

Comment: i know issue is with "FindGameObjectWithTag" function i will have to replace it with some other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to find objects by tag and hidden elements cannot be found using method `FindGameObjectWithTag`. You can use this method:

```
var allObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[]; // this will grab all GameObjects from the current scene!
foreach(GameObejct obj in allObjects) {
    if(new Regex(@"^Button(?'number'\d{1,2})").IsMatch(obj.Tag)) {
        obj.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type. here>>>foreach(GameObejct obj in allObjects)

Comment: [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and see updated answer.

Comment: 195 times done is logged and yet invisible buttons are not showing up

Comment: Because you have to adjust this code to your needs. I don't know what type is your "button" and i don't know how is it tagged. That leads me to just post something "generic" like you see above. Maybe you can show screenshot of hierarchy view?

Comment: my button tags are Button1 Button2 Button3... change my regrex to ^(?:Button)[1-9][0-5] yet no effect on the result

Comment: ^(?:(?:Button)[1-9][0-5])|^(?:(?:Button)[1-9])

Comment: I got the solution if you can post it I can select your answer... "we have to save the object reference of the buttons, before they are hidden"

Comment: After that they can be called as object.setActive(true);